# Python flask controller says "url not found error"

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask import render_template
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound


create_testcases_bp = Blueprint('create_testcases', __name__, template_folder='templates')

create_testcases_bp.url_map.strict_slashes = False


@create_testcases_bp.route('/create_testcases/')
def create_testcases():
    print "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"

    return render_template('/forms/create_testcase_view.html')
```

I am getting 404 URL not found error. Any help? Is there anything I am missing?
URL: http://localhost:8000/create_testcases/

Comment: Have you registered the blueprint with your application? Just creating the blueprint doesn't make the routes available or active, you have to register the blueprint (`app.register_blueprint(create_testcases_bp)`)

Comment: I just did that and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: command added: app.register_blueprint(create_testcases_bp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the blueprint with the application before the routes will have any effect. Just creating the blueprint doesn't make the routes active.

You register the blueprint by calling `register_blueprint` on your app object:

```
app.register_blueprint(create_testcases_bp)
```